# CSS div positioning: ridiculous number for margin-left

Tags: html, css, position, margin

http://jsfiddle.net/SVJaK/1338/

In this fiddle i tired to  make a short space between the green divs and my right div. I had to put a very huge number of px to margin-left to make that little gap. Can you tell me why? The gap is like 50px or something, i had to put a value of 620 to margin-left to make that gap. Is there anything wrong with my nesting of divs? 
I want .right div to be right of green divs. Here is my Code:

```
<div class="nobr">

<div class="className" style="background-color:green; height:100px;" id="IDName" ><a href="#" style="font-weight: bolder;"> Your Text goes here </a></div> 
<div class="className" style="background-color:green; height:100px;" id="IDName" ><a href="#" style="font-weight: bolder;"> Your Text goes here </a></div> 
<div class="className" style="background-color:green; height:100px;" id="IDName" ><a href="#" style="font-weight: bolder;"> Your Text goes here </a></div> 
<div style="clear:both"></div> 

<div class="className" style="background-color:green; height:100px;" id="IDName" ><a href="#" style="font-weight: bolder;"> Your Text goes here </a></div> 
<div class="className" style="background-color:green; height:100px;" id="IDName" ><a href="#" style="font-weight: bolder;"> Your Text goes here </a></div> 
<div class="className" style="background-color:green; height:100px;" id="IDName" ><a href="#" style="font-weight: bolder;"> Your Text goes here </a></div>
<div style="clear:both"></div> 

<div class="className" style="background-color:green; height:100px;" id="IDName" ><a href="#" style="font-weight: bolder;"> Your Text goes here </a></div> 
<div class="className" style="background-color:green; height:100px;" id="IDName" ><a href="#" style="font-weight: bolder;"> Your Text goes here </a></div> 
<div class="className" style="background-color:green; height:100px;" id="IDName" ><a href="#" style="font-weight: bolder;"> Your Text goes here </a></div> 
<div class="className" style="background-color:green; height:100px;" id="IDName" ><a href="#" style="font-weight: bolder;"> Your Text goes here </a></div> 
<div class="className" style="background-color:green; height:100px;" id="IDName" ><a href="#" style="font-weight: bolder;"> Your Text goes here </a></div> 
</div>

<div class="right">this is my right div</div>
```

My CSS is this:

```
a{display:table-cell; height:100%;vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; }
a:hover { background-color:#000;}
div.className {display:table;  width:200px; float:left;}
div.nobr {width:600px; }
div.right {margin-left:620px;}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the correct Fiddle.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited correct fiddle.

Comment: I think you failed to close your `div.nobr` div. Try adding a closing tag before your `div.right` element. Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/SVJaK/1339/) what you meant?

Comment: I edited closing tag for my .nobr. No change to right div.

Comment: Could you clarify your desired behavior, then? When I add the closing tag (see above fiddle), I see `.right` positioned to the right of `.nobr`, and it is positioned thus without any large margin.

Comment: I want .right div to be right of green divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your CSS like below.

```
a{display:table-cell; height:100%;vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; }
a:hover { background-color:#000;}
div.className {display:table;  width:200px; float:left;}
div.nobr {width:600px; float:left;}
div.right { float:left; padding-left:30px;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SVJaK/1342/)

Answer (score 1):

You didnt float left the right div, here http://jsfiddle.net/SVJaK/1341/

```
div.right{float: left;}
```

Comment: No, thats not what i want, right div is now underneath green divs. I want it right of green divs.

Comment: it cant be next to the green with that high margin if you resize the window enough it will be next to the green